# Adding a new CheckBox and a editText views, when the user taps the Done on the keypad in android?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-edittext, android-checkbox, on-screen-keyboard

**I am new to android development**,
What i am trying to achieve is,

When the **user clicks the DONE button via the on-screen keyboard(Soft input method)**, the existing default editText should turn into a checkBox and also again creating an editText so that the user can enter some data again.
These **I can able to do this with creating a button and pressing it** but **I don't want a button**, I **want the on-Screen keyboard interactions such as DONE button**.

first, i tried it with onKeyListener but it doesn't work on the soft keyboard(mobile phone's) instead it worked on the hardware keyboard such as the laptop keyboard.

and then i can also able to do the above-mentioned function via the On-Screen Keyboard using the **onEditerActionListener()**, **but only once I can do this and after that**, the **DONE button disappears from the on-Screen keyboard, the ENTER button replaces the DONE button**

When for the first i try to enter some data into the editText the DONE button is available and after the ENTER BUTTON replaces it.

**1) is there any way to stop the ENTER button from replacing the DONE button on the on_Screen keyboard?

2) OR is there any way to also give the functionality to the enter key also?**

##### XML CODE,

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/defaultEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

##### ANDROID CODE,

```
    this.constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    this.defaultEditText = findViewById(R.id.defaultEditText);

    defaultEditText.setOnEditorActionListener( new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

           
            //CREATING A CHECKBOX
            //CREATIN A EDITTEXT
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

#### output,

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you any solution?

Comment: Nope, i quit android development.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `maxLines=1` & `imeOptions="actionDone"` to indicate that you **don't** want to `enter` the new line & you're `done`. This would always give your expected output.

So your `EdiText` would look something like this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/defaultEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: But for the next time, it doesn't provide a option to click done.

Comment: @mockingbird I tried testing this on multiple devices & it worked. So can you please provide some code for the "Next time" thing that you're saying. How're you implementing that?